# jQuery - Stay at bottom of page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Imagine a table with a thread of messages that fills the page - the user will automatically be scrolled down to the end of the thread and the bottom of the page. There is a textarea at the bottom which, through ajax and php, sends a message on button click and appends the table.

Here is the code to do that:

```
//Call script to send message
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'action/sendmessage.php',
    data: 'partner='+partner+'&message='+message,
    success: function(feedback){
        var json=$.parseJSON(feedback);
        if(json.success=='true'){
            $('#messagetext').val('');
            $('table > tbody:last').hide().after(json.message).show(200);
            $('#messagetext').focus();
        }
    }
}).error(function(){
    alert('The message could not be sent - please try again later.');
});
```

The neat thing about this is that the effect works and all. However, through appending the table, the user gets "pushed" to about 100px *above* the bottom of the page - he doesn't stay *at* the bottom.

How can I solve that so that after sending a message and appending the table, the user still stays at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move to the bottom of the page you can use the `scrollTop()` method. Personally I would animate the scrolling, as the page moving by itself could confuse some of your users. Try this:

```
success: function(feedback){
    var json = $.parseJSON(feedback);
    if (json.success=='true'){
        $('#messagetext').val('');
        $('table > tbody:last').hide().after(json.message).show(200);
        $('#messagetext').focus();

        // animate scrolling to bottom of the page
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500); 

        // jump directly to the bottom of the page
        //$("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! But is there any way to push the content of the page to the top instead of scrolling down? Even when I change the effect to 0 seconds, the user can still see the scrolling...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I animated the effect because IMO it's better for UX. I've updated my answer with a version which will jump directly to the bottom of the page with no animation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function somehwere

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(doc.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Then add this to the handler:

```
window.scrollTo(0, getDocHeight());
```

It will scroll the page to the bottom.

That should solve your problem.